# React redux sharing whole pages dependency injection

Tags: reactjs, dependency-injection, react-hooks, redux-saga

My team develops a few different React applications that share similar components and pages.
how would approach sharing whole pages within different React applications? given that these pages have large amount of components in different hierarchies and each application has its own implementation of accessing the backend?

we are using React, React hooks, Redux, Saga.

Answer (score 1):

In the end those pages are React components, so best way would be to identify all common components in the different React applications your team is developing, and create a component library to put all those components so the are all in a single code base, and is easier to maintain and use. I recommend you check this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-library
I have used before, is really easy to get it run. Still you can create a new library on your own, but this library will save you some time.

Another approach would be a step forward using micro-frontends architecture, I haven't used yet but looks really promising.
You can check this link https://micro-frontends.org/ and are many resources out there to learn about it. Like I said, I haven't used yet so I can't make you any recommendations about it.

If you decide to use a library for common components, then you can pass actions and hooks you need to execute in the library as props to the components in the library

```js
export const RegisterView = ({ login, useMutation, useQuery, ...props }) => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState('')
  const [submitError, setSubmitError] = useState(null)
  const [register, { loading }] = useMutation(REGISTER)
  const { data: duplicatedUsername } = useQuery(CHECK_IF_USERNAME_EXIST, {
    skip: !username,
    variables: { username }
  })
  const { data: duplicatedEmail } = useQuery(CHECK_IF_EMAIL_EXIST, {
    skip: !email,
    variables: { email }
  })
  const { data: duplicatedPhone } = useQuery(CHECK_IF_PHONE_EXIST, {
    skip: !phone,
    variables: { phone }
  })
```

the component is too large, this is only a fragment, but hope this shows the case you will probably need to use. In this case useQuery, useMutation are hooks from apollo-client I'm passing from the app, the schemas for this calls are also in the library. The login prop is also a hook that calls the right login request, so the RegisterView component only receive those props coming from the app where is being imported and executes them.
Whatever logic your common component need to use or execute that is not shared between all apps, you must put it outside the library and pass it as props.

The create-react-library package also comes with a react app inside to test the components in your library so you are able to debug them and test them in isolation on the apps where you will import them.

Comment: How would you use the store in these pages? For example, I have a page showing alerts that I want to use in two different applications, how would you get the alert data in the common component library?

Comment: You have different options for that: You can create a reducer in the library, export it and import it in the diferent apps where you configure your store. Or you can just pass the actions like props to the common components.

Comment: You can even pass the hooks you need to use in your common components in the library as props from the app.

Comment: The page has a lot of components with different hierarchies, passing everything using props will be very cumbersome, we want to utilize the store to do that in a more comfortable way, any thought on how to do that?

Comment: BTW because the backend implementation is different micro frontends isn't really an option

Comment: Then you can do what I suggested. Create the reducers you need inside the library and export them just like you export the components. When you create the library, in the index.js you must export all components, functions and everything you may need to export to use outside in the apps. Just export your reducers and then in the apps import that reducers from the library and merge them with the `combineReducers`

Comment: Of course you will need to install `redux` and `react-redux` in the library, and if you need to test it in the example app inside the library, you also need to install those dependencies in the example project inside the library, since they are separated projects with different packages.json files